# Jquery delegate/live does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have system that I'm modifying that uses **jquery 1.5.1**, which means `.on` doesn't exist.

I have a table and in this table I have multiple links listed in a row, and when the user clicks it opens a pop up window. I have the following code to create a pop up link.

```
 <tr>
        <td class="view_detail_label">

        </td>
        <td>

           @Html.ActionLink(
           training.Name.Name,
           "AddSurvey",
           new
           {
               employeeId = Model.Id,
               trainingId = training.Id
           },
           new
           {
               @class = "addSurvey"
           }
       )

          <div class="result" style="display:none;"></div>

        </td>

    </tr>
```

In the first function below I open a popup window and it works perfectly except when you close the popup you can not reopen it from the link again. To solve this I subscribed my event lively and used delegate and live function. But when tracking it from the console I cannot seen any output from the console statement : `console.log($(this).next('.result'));`.

```
 $('.addSurvey').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        title: 'Anket',
                        width: 500,
                        height: 'auto',
                        modal: true

                    }); //end of dialog
                    //console.log($(this).next('.result'));
                } //enf of success function

            }); //end of ajax call
            return false;
        });

        $('a.addSurvey').live( 'click', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        title: 'Anket',
                        width: 500,
                        height: 'auto',
                        modal: true

                    }); //end of dialog
                console.log($(this).next('.result'));
                } //enf of success function

            }); //end of ajax call

        }); //end of live
```

Why is this the case I used delegate method too and it does not work either. My delegate 
function:

```
 $(document).delegate(".addSurvey", "click", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Anket',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true

                }); //end of dialog
                console.log($(this).next('.result'));
            } //enf of success function

        }); //end of ajax call

    });//end of delegate
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 1 After clesing the popup window when i click it it duplicates the responses somehow it is clicked as twice and when i refresh the page and click on it and then close the responses triples. What might cause this awkward situation? ** 
**EDIT2 I solved the above problem by using  `close: function () { console.log("onClose"); $('.surveyTable').load('Home/DetailsSurvey', {id:@Model.Id}); }`. By this I reload the the div table and can click on any pop up.

Comment: Have you checked if your success callback is being fired? You can create `error` or `complete` callbacks to check this.

Comment: In complete I did the following; 'complete: function(){console.log("Test");}'. This writes response Test to console each time I click on the link and i did the same thing for the error it does not give a response in the console. It seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone I solved my problem as follows: on close action of the popup I reload the page from the server and re render it therefor now it works like a charm. Thanks everyone for your time and attention.

```
$('a.addSurvey').live('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Anket',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    close: function () { console.log("onClose"); $('.surveyTable').load('Home/DetailsSurvey', {id:@Model.Id}); }
                }); //end of dialog
                console.log($(this).next('.result'));
            }, //enf of success function
            complete: function () {
                console.log("Complete");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }); //end of ajax call
    });   //end o
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `live` then you do not need the first call. Try `preventDefault()` rather than `return false`.

```
$('a.addSurvey').live( 'click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Anket',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true

                }); //end of dialog
            console.log($(this).next('.result'));
            } //enf of success function

        }); //end of ajax call

    }); //end of live
```

Comment: Using the code you provided I can see the response in the console, but still the popup link is not working after popup closed. What might cause this case?Should delegate work or delegate works in different manner?

Comment: See the answer just added by @undefined

Comment: I think his answer is deleted I cache it but it replaced the content rather opening popup

Comment: I can update my answer to reflect what he said, but are you still having an issue with what he added?

Comment: Yes the pop up does not open, instead it replaces the content of the page

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
$(".addSurvey").die().live("click", function (event) { event.stopPropagation();
```

.......rest of code.

Comment: thank you for your answer judson but this does not work it does not give any response at the console (not firing ajax code). It does not open pop up but it replaces the content of the page

Comment: Have you tried destroying the dialog on close? Add the close event to the dialog then close: function(){ $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); }

Comment: I destroyed the dialog on close. I put console log to see if it enters the function. It entered the function and closed. But same problems are occuring.

Answer (score -1):

use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live. live is deprecated..

```
$('a.addSurvey').on( 'click', function () {

}
```

Comment: He's using jQuery 1.5.1 which doesn't support `on` which was added in 1.7

Answer (score -2):

on() method is the new replacement for the bind(), live() and delegate() methods. Please use on().

Comment: He has specified he is using jQuery 1.5.1. I'm sure he doesn't want to upgrade for the sake of a single call.